# $.each() is not loading

Tags: jquery, filereader, each

I have jquery:

```
$(".upload-cont").bind('drop',function(e){
    var files=e.dataTransfer.files;
    e.preventDefault();
    $.each(files, function(index, file){
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function(file) {
            return function(e) { 
            };
        })(files[index]);
   });
```

how to pass the value to the file in **$.each()**

Comment: Add `console.log(files);` before `each`. Probably it's undefined.

Comment: It didnt work yeasterday. but it is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't normalize the `dataTransfer` object so you'll have to access it from the original event

```
var files=e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
```

Comment: is originalEvent an object

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/KJa3M/